# XPath Sibling returns empty

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I'm using this http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5a30592045b6aa5089faf909261ede0b XPath tester, which returns exactly what I want.  For some reason it removes my full query, but if you use it, it works.

***/h3[contains(string(), "Description")]/following-sibling::p[1]**

But in real life, I get nothing from my variable.

I'm trying to get the data after `<h3>Description</h3>`, in this case a paragraph `<p>`.

**HTML**
$feed_item=

```
<div class="outer-feed"><ul>
<li><strong>Severity:</strong> <span class="label label-info">Low</span></li>
</ul>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>The lack of validation of configuration parameters used in SQL queries caused various SQL injection vectors.</p>
...
```

Here's my **XPath**

```
$description_node = $xpath->query('*/h3[contains(string(), "Description")]/following-sibling::p[1]', $feed_item);
$description = "description: " . $description_node->item(0)->textContent;
```

and **var_dump**

```
object(DOMNodeList)#1654 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

And the **error**

```
Notice
: Trying to get property 'textContent' of non-object in
```

What confuses me is that **I can get Severity** from the same HTML by using this:

```
$severity_node = $xpath->query('*/li[contains(string(), "Severity:")]', $feed_item);
$severity = preg_replace('/Severity:\W*/u', '', $severity_node->item(0)->textContent);
```

My first thought was to scale back to just the H3 and output that.

```
$description_node = $xpath->query('*/h3[contains(string(), "Description")]', $feed_item);
object(DOMNodeList)#1654 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } // doesn't contain anything
```

Given that the following are identical but the first works and the second doesn't, what could be the problem?

```
$severity_node = $xpath->query('*/li[contains(string(), "Severity:")]', $feed_item);
$description_node = $xpath->query('*/h3[contains(string(), "Description")]', $feed_item);
```

Why is one working and not the other.  And what is the best way to troubleshoot things like this.  It seems to work on the xpathtester.  What could I be doing wrong that causes this problem in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this XPath:

```
//h3[text()="Description"]/following::p[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A query starting `*/h3[...]` will only work if the context item when it is invoked is the grandparent of the `h3` element. You've given no information about the context item, so I suspect it is something different.

You ask the question(s): "Why is one working and not the other. And what is the best way to troubleshoot things like this. It seems to work on the xpathtester. What could I be doing wrong that causes this problem in PHP?"

Well, the first thing is to understand that XPath expressions may depend on the context item, and that the same expression evaluated with different context items is going to give different results. Once you understand that concept, it hopefully becomes a lot clearer.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance.  Isn't HTML the context item?  Or else the `<p>` following the description?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what XPath API you are using, but I think the context item is probably whatever is in `$feed_item`, and you haven't shown us what that variable contains.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes the HTML is `$feed_item` I'll update my question. I'm using PHP `DOMDocument`